# Initialize outer scope variable in class function

Tags: c++, arduino-uno, platformio

I am new to C++ I come from a C# background. I am creating an Arduino project using c++ using vs code thanks to https://docs.platformio.org/ .

**The following code works and turns on my led strip:**

**main.cpp**

```
#include <Arduino.h>   
#include <LedStrip.h>

// pin where led strip is connected
#define LED_STIP_PIN 4

// number of leds in the strip
#define LED_STRIP_COUNT 7

// My wrapper class
LedStrip myLedStripWrapper;


void setup() {
   // empty
}

void loop() {
   
    myLedStripWrapper.setup(LED_STRIP_COUNT, LED_STIP_PIN);

    // myLedStripWrapper.foo1();  // <<<HERE-1>>>
    
    // wait forever
    while (true) {
        delay(1);
    }       
}
```

**LedStrip.h**

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

class LedStrip
{

public:
    
    Adafruit_NeoPixel strip;

    void setup(uint16_t led_count, uint16_t pin)
    {
        // Declare our NeoPixel strip object:
        Adafruit_NeoPixel a(led_count, pin, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);                
        strip = a;

        // INITIALIZE NeoPixel strip
        strip.begin();            
        strip.show();            
        strip.setBrightness(15); 

        foo1();     // <<<HERE-2>>> <------------------- calling foo1 from here turns on the led strip           
    }

    
    // Color led strip blue
    void foo1()
    {
        uint32_t color = strip.Color(0, 0, 100);
        for (uint16_t i = 0; i < strip.numPixels(); i++)
        {                                  // For each pixel in strip...
            strip.setPixelColor(i, color); //  Set pixel's color (in RAM)
            strip.show();                  //  Update strip to match
            // delay(100);
        }
    }
};
```

Note that in the code I have labels `<<<HERE-1>>>` and `<<<HERE-2>>>`. I want to call function `foo1` from `<<<HERE-1>>>`. **Why is it that if I uncomment `<<<HERE-1>>>` and comment `<<<HERE-2>>>` the code does not work and the LED strip does not turn on?** In other words I do not want to call foo1 from within the class wrapper. I am just calling it form there because it only works if I call it form there.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Adruino, but my guess is that `Adafruit_NeoPixel` destructor, triggered by `a` local variable going out of scope, does something to disable the strip. You are probably not supposed to have two instances of `Adafruit_NeoPixel` in your program.

Comment: Yes `Adafruit_NeoPixel` has a desctructor that disables the led strip. How can I prevent calling teh destructor? I want to initialize the strip variable from within the `setup` function in my `LedStrip` class

Comment: Just checked the code on github. [Rule of Three violation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: Looking at `Adafruit_NeoPixel` constructor implementation, you could probably just call `updateLength`, `updateType` and `setPin` on `strip` directly, without constructing a local variable.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yes I guess I will do that. I was just hoping I could create a wrapper class.

Comment: I mean, do that in `LedStrip::setup`, instead of creating `a` variable. Nothing I said precludes using `LedStrip` wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The writers of that class made a grade-school C++ mistake and didn't correctly observe the [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). This means an `Adafruit_NeoPixel` object can be copied when it is not safe to do so.

```
void setup(uint16_t led_count, uint16_t pin)
{
    // Declare our NeoPixel strip object:
    Adafruit_NeoPixel a(led_count, pin, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);                
    strip = a; // copy here. Both a and strip point to a shared resource

    // INITIALIZE NeoPixel strip
    strip.begin();            
    strip.show();            
    strip.setBrightness(15); 
} // a goes out of scope here and frees the shared resource in its 
  // destructor. Oops.
```

The easiest fix is to initialize `strip` in `LedStrip`'s constructor where it doesn't need to be copied.

To ensure `strip` isn't copied, you're going to have to prevent `LedStrip` from being copied or implement special member functions that allow `LedStrip` to be copied without copying `strip`. In the example below I will simply prevent copying.

If copying is required consider replacing `Adafruit_NeoPixel strip;` with `std::shared_ptr<Adafruit_NeoPixel> strip;` so a pointer will be copied rather than an object that can turn into a bomb when copied.

```cpp
class LedStrip
{

public:
    
    Adafruit_NeoPixel strip; // you sure you want this public?
    //  adding constructor so we don't have to copy a Adafruit_NeoPixel  object
    LedStrip(uint16_t led_count, uint16_t pin): 
        strip(led_count, pin, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800) // this is a member initializer list
                                                    // It allows us to construct strip 
                                                    // without having to copy anything.
                                                    // more on that later
    {
        // INITIALIZE NeoPixel strip
        strip.begin();            
        strip.show();            
        strip.setBrightness(15); 
    }

    // preventing copying of LedStrip
    LedStrip(const LedStrip& ) = delete;
    LedStrip & operator=(const LedStrip& ) = delete;
    // note if the compiler doesn't like the = delete, remove it, make 
    // the copy constructor and assignment operator private, and do not 
    // implement them

    
    // Color led strip blue
    void foo1()
    {
        uint32_t color = strip.Color(0, 0, 100);
        for (uint16_t i = 0; i < strip.numPixels(); i++)
        {                                  // For each pixel in strip...
            strip.setPixelColor(i, color); //  Set pixel's color (in RAM)
            strip.show();                  //  Update strip to match
            // delay(100);
        }
    }
private:
/* only needed if the = delete trick above doesn't work.
    LedStrip(const LedStrip& );
    LedStrip & operator=(const LedStrip& );
*/
};
```

Then

```
LedStrip myLedStripWrapper;
```

becomes

```
LedStrip myLedStripWrapper(LED_STRIP_COUNT, LED_STIP_PIN);
```

and

```
myLedStripWrapper.setup(LED_STRIP_COUNT, LED_STIP_PIN);
```

vanishes from the world, never to be seen again.

[Documentation on the Member Initializer List.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor)

[Documentation on `std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)